# cbind in time-series data

Tags: r, cbind

Here is a simple example that works fine:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
d = 65; e = 66; f = 77
m1 = cbind(a, b, c); m2 = cbind(d, e, f); M = cbind(m1, m2)
colnames(M)
#   [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

But, now try exactly the same thing with time-series data:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
d = 65; e = 66; f = 77
m1 = as.ts(cbind(a, b, c)); m2 = as.ts(cbind(d, e, f)); M = cbind(m1, m2)
colnames(M)
#   [1] "m1.a" "m1.b" "m1.c" "m2.d" "m2.e" "m2.f"'
```

How do I avoid these prefixes for time series data?
(i.e:  the prefixes `m1.` and `m2.`)

PS: Obviously I know we can just do a direct "cbind" command on `a, b, c, d, e, f` bypassing `m1` and `m2`, but I need these intermediate staged matrices in a loop.

Comment: Your example has a typo. Please correct it.

Comment: (…typo resolved, thank you.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't explain why, but `cbind.data.frame` works the same for both:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
d = 65; e = 66; f = 77
m1 = cbind(a, b, c)
m2 = cbind(d, e, f)
M = cbind.data.frame(m1, m2)
colnames(M)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

m1 = as.ts(cbind(a, b, c))
m2 = as.ts(cbind(d, e, f))
M = cbind.data.frame(m1, m2)
colnames(M)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: many thanks zx8754, I appreciate this, but if you don't mind, I will keep this question open for a little while longer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent `cbind.ts` from doing this.  The usual way you would prevent it would be to set `deparse.level=0`, but `cbind.ts` ignores it.

```
R> stats:::cbind.ts
function (..., deparse.level = 1) 
{
    if (deparse.level != 1) 
        .NotYetUsed("deparse.level != 1")
    .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = FALSE, union = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x35531f8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

You can always set the `colnames` yourself, just be careful they are "valid" (e.g. via `make.names`) and not duplicated, or you might have issues later in your analysis.

```
colnames(M) <- make.names(c(colnames(m1), colnames(m2)))
```

Comment: I am not a good Asker…
many thanks Joshua, but this is exactly what I was trying to avoid

:-)

Comment: Given the information you've provided, I don't see any way to avoid it.  If you provide more details about your actual problem, someone may be able to give you a solution that avoids doing something like this.

Comment: Hello again Joshua, I want to avoid assigning the colnames manually.

I have been doing it your way with:

    colnames(M) = c(colnames(m1), colnames(m2)

directly after the cbind.  (Out of interest, is there an additional benefit to using "make.names()" around my "c()" command?)

The solution provided by zx8754 comes close to beating my/our current way of doing it, but cbind.data.frame also requires an additional command because class(M) is now "data.frame", and I am working with time-series data.

What would you do?

Thanks again

Comment: `make.names` ensures column names are "valid" R names. I would do what I suggested in my answer. I wouldn't do what [zx8754 answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29298233/271616) because there's a potential that the time series would not merge properly.

Comment: yes, I was worried about this.   time to end this question, thanks to both of you.